# How to prevent the java process icon display in mac

Tags: java, macos

When I start the java process, it will always display the java icon in dock under mac. I have added the following line to .profile, but still not working

export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dapple.awt.UIElement="true"

anyone could help ?

Comment: I believe you know need to package the program in an .app bundle and modify the .plist, but there's so much erroneous information it's difficult to be 100% sure

Answer (score 2):

Either in your Java code, add this:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

Or at the command-line, add this:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar myProg.jar
```